# Input iframe stop work on IOS in second tap ionic v1

Tags: javascript, ios, ionic-framework, iframe, webview

I have an ionic v1 application which has an `iframe`. I try to write in an input field and it's ok. But when I do a second tap on the input I can't write anymore. This happens only in IOS; With any `iframe` on Android that has an input field in it it works perfectly.

I have tried to handle the focus and touch events through `window.addEventListener` but it still does not work. I also tried to trigger keyboard up and down. I have many weeks with this incident if you could help me I would be very grateful. In this link I leave some evidence [Video Evidence](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Zc605_FJhQxmKYZ0pzUC93ozY-tDhifx)

```
    window.addEventListener('blur', function() {

        focusElement();

    });
    window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', focusElement);

    function focusElement() {

        $timeout(function() {
            var iframe = document.getElementById('ofertasExclusivasIframe');
            iframe.contentWindow.focus();
            console.log("----------loaded---------", iframe)
        }, 250);
    }

    $scope.$on('$destroy', handleDestroy);

    function handleDestroy() {
        $window.removeEventListener('native.keyboardshow', focusElement);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by keeping the focus constantly by being in the view where the iframe is

```html
if (typeof cordova !== 'undefined' && $cordovaDevice.getPlatform() === 'iOS') {
window.setInterval(function() {
   var myFrame = document.getElementById('Iframe');
   myFrame.contentWindow.focus();
}, 500);
}
```